# Seemingly Random ssl.SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, openssl, tls1.2

**Goal:** To auth into an API consistently using python's request library locally.

Currently, I successfully auth at what seems to be random chunks of 20-30mins throughout the day. The remaining attempts receive an error:

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error
```

In addition, when I push this to AWS and execute from there--no issues.

**Trace:**

```
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Code\atlas\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Code\atlas\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Code\atlas\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Code\atlas\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 411, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Code\atlas\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 428, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Code\atlas\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 472, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\Austin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\Austin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Austin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1123)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Code\atlas\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Code\atlas\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Code\atlas\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 573, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='blacknotchportal.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /Bnotchsvc/Bnotchsvc.svc/Login (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1123)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Austin/Desktop/Code/atlas/src/main.py", line 169, in api_auth
    resp_login = requests.post(url + "/Login", json=login_params)
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Code\atlas\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 119, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Code\atlas\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Code\atlas\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Code\atlas\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Code\atlas\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='blacknotchportal.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /Bnotchsvc/Bnotchsvc.svc/Login (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1123)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Austin/Desktop/Code/atlas/src/main.py", line 43, in main
    token = api_auth(url, login_params)
  File "C:/Users/Austin/Desktop/Code/atlas/src/main.py", line 175, in api_auth
    raise Exception("Exception occurred during auth, check logs for details")
Exception: Exception occurred during auth, check logs for details

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Code\atlas\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Code\atlas\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Code\atlas\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Code\atlas\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 411, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Code\atlas\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 428, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Code\atlas\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 472, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\Austin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\Austin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Austin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1123)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Code\atlas\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Code\atlas\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Code\atlas\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 573, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='blacknotchportal.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /Bnotchsvc/Bnotchsvc.svc/Login (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1123)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Austin/Desktop/Code/atlas/src/main.py", line 169, in api_auth
    resp_login = requests.post(url + "/Login", json=login_params)
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Code\atlas\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 119, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Code\atlas\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Code\atlas\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Code\atlas\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Code\atlas\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='blacknotchportal.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /Bnotchsvc/Bnotchsvc.svc/Login (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1123)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Austin/Desktop/Code/atlas/src/main.py", line 265, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Austin/Desktop/Code/atlas/src/main.py", line 46, in main
    token = api_auth(url, login_params)
  File "C:/Users/Austin/Desktop/Code/atlas/src/main.py", line 175, in api_auth
    raise Exception("Exception occurred during auth, check logs for details")
Exception: Exception occurred during auth, check logs for details
```

I have tried all the other solutions I could find: python version, OPENSSL version, windows firewall, changing crypto standards, forcing different versions of TLS etc.

**python 3.8; requests==2.25.1**

```
import ssl
print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)

OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
```

**Code:**

```
import requests
import json
import logging


def api_auth(url: str, login_params: dict) -> str:
    """
    :param url: url to call
    :param login_params: parameters required for login
    :return: a token for auth in future api calls
    """
    try:
        resp_login = requests.post(url + "/Login", json=login_params)
        resp_data = json.loads(resp_login.text)
        print(resp_data)
        token = str(resp_data["token"])
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception("Exception occurred during auth")
        raise

    return token


try:
    token = api_auth(url, login_params)
except:
    logging.info('attempting reauth')
    token = api_auth(url, login_params)
```

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be server side issue with a data provider. The fact my AWS version worked threw me off from this.

The URL I was hitting was deprecated leading to intermittent connection issues as it was no longer being supported.